# How to create a div using wrap() and then select it in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am doing the following within a jquery plugin and I'm looking a way to select the divs after they are created.  I'd like to avoid giving them an id as then I would need to concern myself with making the id unique.

```
$('.something').wrap('<div />');
```

also:

```
$('.something').after('<div></div>');
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('.something').wrap('<div />').parent();
```

and

```
$('.something').after('<div></div>').next();
```

Each of these calls will return one element for each element in the original set.